# SQL how to work with a single user instead of all of them

Tags: python, sql, database, sockets

So I created a basic SQL table with usernames and password I did signup and it all went great. Now let me just make something clear, if you are not logged in you can not visit the site at all except the login and signup. I have a column named `"onlineORoffline"` that turns online when the user connects to the server but when I do the statement

```
status = user_info[5] #user_info[5] is rather he is online or not
 if status == 'online':..
```

if he is online he can access the site but the problem is anyone can access the site, not just the user who just signed in but everyone who just comes to the site because he is online so this statement is true until the user logs off the site. So how do I do it so it will only apply on him and not everyone who logs in the server (for the backend I am using python socket). I am doing it on python is there a way I could ONLY work with the single client who logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many tutorials about setting up server authentication systems, but here is a short answer.  For production use instead of learning the better answer is usually to use an existing library or framework that has been tested by other people.

Instead of setting "online" in the database, generate a unique value of some kind.  (One quick and probably not very secure way: An md5 hash of the current server time + user ID + some secret)

Set that value as a cookie in the user's browser, along with the user's ID.

Store that value as a current session field in the database.

Instead of checking "online" in the database, check that the browser has the user ID and session cookie set. Look up the current session ID for the user ID in the database and see if they match.  If not, show "session expired" and the login page.

SQL injection: sanitize the inputs and use a stored procedure or a safe library that protects against "Little Bobby Tables" where they stuff commands into the ID or session cookies.

More details:

If a browser goes to your page it will have one of these:

- no cookies: just show login page
- user ID cookie, session ID cookie: validate, if valid then treat as logged in

When a user logs in, you set the user ID and session ID cookie and UPDATE the database.  Since this is the only time you set the session ID cookie, no other person or browser is ever logged in at the same time.

Validation:

To validate, you can do a safe SELECT or stored procedure using the user ID and session ID.  For example (this is PHP PDO not Python)

```
SELECT SessionID FROM LoginTable WHERE UserID = ? LIMIT 1;
```

If (SessionID == the session ID cookie) then they are logged in.  Every page you want to secure needs to check this.

Database

```
UserID  UserNmae  SessionID
1234    Fred      1234abcd1234abcd...
1235    Barney    null
1236    Wilma     7fe0320a....
```

SessionID changes every time that user successfully logs in because the server generates a new value and stores it to the database and in the headers of the response page for a successful login.

So if Wilma has Firefox and Chrome open and logs in with Firefox, it will get a session cookie of "7fe0320a...." and it is logged in.

But Chrome will NOT have that cookie so it gets the login page.  If Wilma then logs in with Chrome, the database row SessionID changes to "abcd0f03..." and Chrome is given that as its session cookie.

Now Firefox still has its "7fe0320a...." cookie but that cookie does not match the database which now has  "abcd0f03...".  It is not valid, so Firefox gets the login page and must log in again.

Comment: so every time the user logs out the cookie will not be available? And how do I view the cookie?

Comment: You can choose to set either a session cookie that disappears when the browser is closed, or a persistent cookie set to expire X days from now.  Either way only the one browser will have this session cookie set.  Someone else (or even a different browser on the same PC) will be missing the cookie so you send them to the login page.

Comment: But how do I set it up? do I need to create a new column named "cookie" and put that column in the user browser? how do I put it in the browser

Comment: When the user fills out the login form, if the user + password are correct you store the session value in the database, and you add to the "headers" for the response page you send back to set it as a cookie in the browser.  Search here and/or see here for cookies:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html

Comment: Alright I get it. I already check if the user data is correct so all I need to do now is put in the response the header of the cookie but then how do I get the cookie?

Comment: @allenfromspace I understand that but when I send the cookie in the http response what value should I send? the ID of the user and by what do I hash after? like what string?

Comment: There are a few schools of thought on this, but the best practice is to execute your cookies then send them with HTTP.

Comment: For learning, you could just use something like session ID = MD5 ( (current time) + "my secret (change this)" + user-id ) .  It's just some unique one-time value that should be hard for an attacker to generate themselves.  You mix in current time so every new log in gets a different value.  Or you could just generate 5 random numbers and mash them together with the secret.  Also, you want 2 cookies or a 2 part cookie: user ID, session ID, -or- session ID = user-id - hash

Comment: @DaveS I don't understand what I do with the name though i did that the name is the user ID but how do I do it so it will only be him anyway?

Comment: The name or user ID cookie lets you look up only one row of your database, and lets you know who it is not just that they are logged in.  Since you store the session ID for that user in their own table row, only one person and one browser can be logged in as that user at a time.  If personr #2 goes to the login page and uses it with the same user ID / user name, the session ID will change and person #1 is logged out.

Comment: Example added to the answer.